# how to Get file from folder of sd card in list view

Tags: android

```
private String getFilename() {
            String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            }
            return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + file_exts[currentFormat]);
        }
```

Can i get my recorded file in list by its name.
This is my code and i am getting list of my recorded file but i am not getting it by its name.
i have try to get it by name but its coming with folder name always, whole list is showing folder name in each recorder item.

this helps to get data.

```
final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/Recording/");
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

public Activity_Song() {

}

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
    File file = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
    if (file.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
        for (File file1 : file.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
            song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
            song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

            // Adding each song to SongList
            songsList.add(song);
        }
    }
    return songsList;
}

class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the file name you should use `file.getName()` instead of `file.getAbsolutePath()`